# Multi-Threaded Data Entity

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, entity-framework

I want to rewrite my program that currently uses DataSets over WinForms and move it to WPF.
Currently the program is using Citrix for the users in order to login.
Now when someone is doing some sort of action on the data the main thread is committing the BI on the change and sending it back to the Server, or getting a new data (or modified data) from the server and adding it to the cache.
The problem today is the extensive use of locks and unlocks every time that a user is working on the data or a message arrives from the server.
I'm looking for a data entity or some way to work multithreaded in my client side.
That means that I would like that every thread will be able to commit the BI on the data and communicate with the server while been synchronized with all the other users and their changes.

I looked at EF but it is not thread safe meaning when an update will arrive from the server I'll need to lock my EF and update it and again when the user works on the data inside of the EF.

Is there any way to do it more easily without making the programmer lock/unlock the data every time?

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating the multithreaded application , you cannot avoid the locks.

here is few thing you can apply while using EF :

1. Don't use a unique context with locks (no singleton pattern).
2. Instantiate and dispose one context per request and some concurrency
   control system
3. avoid lock on context as much as possible.

Comment: My problem is that I want to avoid the need to lock my EF every time there is an update.

Saying I'm only in my client side, which runs more then one user, each on his own thread.
My GUI thread is one.

Saying user A is watching data A1 inside the grid, and user B is editing the same data.
How can I make sure easily without using locks every time someone updates the data that I won't get an exception?
No DB is involved in the process I just want that the update will come to the other users.